# "...the person or body who/which..." is not only a question about whether to refer to companies with "who" or "which"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

["...the person or body who..." vs. "...the person or body which..."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/437161/the-person-or-body-who-vs-the-person-or-body-which)

As far as I can see, this question does not ask only about whether to refer to companies with "who" or "which". If the answer to that happens to be "who", it would resolve the specific example in the question, but the supposed "duplicate" (['Who' or 'which' in reference to companies](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138110/who-or-which-in-reference-to-companies)) does not resolve the additional question about **whether to use "who" or "which" after noun phrases of differing animacy that are linked together by a conjunction** (in this case, "or").

It's true that the [original form of the question](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/437161/1) had a title that made it look like a duplicate, but the text of the question has included the examples with "or" from the beginning.

Please vote to reopen the question, or post an answer here if you think it should not be reopened.